# How to pass an arbitrary sized matrix to a function in Rust?

Tags: matrix, types, rust

I have a 3x3 matrix (a 2D array) passed to a function:

```
let matrix: [[i32; 3]; 3] = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]
];

filter::convolve(&mut image, matrix, 1).unwrap();
```

The function is currently hardwired to accept 3x3 matrix:

```
pub fn convolve(src: &mut Image, matrix: [[i32; 3]; 3], divisor: i32) -> Result<&mut Image, String> {
    // ...
}
```

How would I pass a 3x3, 5x5, or any arbitrarily sized matrix to the same function?

Comment: Have you read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/)? Specifically, I'm thinking of the [**Primitive Types** section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/primitive-types.html), which introduces [*slices*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/primitive-types.html#slices).

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes of course. However its not apparent how to do it with 2D array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Arrays have a fixed size, determined at compile time. [*Slices*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-03-slices.html) have a fixed size, determined at **run-time**.

The easiest thing to do is to accept a slice of slices:

```
fn convolve(matrix: &[&[i32]]) {
    println!("{:?}", matrix);
}

fn main() {
    let matrix = &[
        &[0, 0, 0][..],
        &[0, 1, 0][..],
        &[0, 0, 0][..],
    ];
    convolve(matrix);
}
```

That's a bit annoying, as you have to use the *slicing syntax* (`&foo[..]`) to convert the literal arrays to slices. You could also accept a generic, which allows you to accept the above, but also anything that can be converted to a slice:

```
fn convolve<T, I>(matrix: &[T])
where
    T: AsRef<[I]>,
    I: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    for part in matrix {
        println!("{:?}", part.as_ref());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let matrix = &[
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
    ];
    convolve(matrix);
}
```

As [kosinix points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051788/how-to-pass-an-arbitrary-sized-matrix-to-a-function-in-rust/41052093?noredirect=1#comment69355243_41052093), there is no guarantee that `&[&[i32]]` will have rows of equal lengths; it's possible to have a *ragged array*.

The run-time solution to that is to iterate through all the rows and ensure all the lengths are the same. This can be reduced to checking just once if you create a *newtype* for matrices you have validated:

```
struct Matrix<'a, T: 'a>(&'a [&'a [T]]);

impl<'a, T> Matrix<'a, T> {
    fn new(slice: &'a [&'a [T]]) -> Result<Self, ()> {
        if slice.is_empty() {
            return Ok(Matrix(slice));
        }

        let (head, tail) = slice.split_at(1);
        let expected = head[0].len();

        if tail.iter().map(|row| row.len()).all(|l| l == expected) {
            Ok(Matrix(slice))
        } else {
            Err(()) // return a real error here
        }
    }
}
```

Now, whenever you have a `Matrix`, you can be sure the rows are all the same length.

The compile-time solution... doesn't exist yet. These are called [const generics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2000). The **proposed syntax** would be

```
fn convolve<const N: usize>(matrix: [[i32; N]; N])
```

There are stable workarounds available (such as [generic-array](https://crates.io/crates/generic-array)), but these may be limited in one fashion or another.

Comment: Another problem with using slices is that there is no guarantee that &[&[i32]] will have rows of equal lengths: let matrix = &[[3, 3, 3],[4, 4, 4, 4],[3, 3, 3]];